# Invariant Subspace Counterexample

Tags: linear-algebra, examples-counterexamples

Can someone give an example:

Suppose $T \in L(V)$. If $V = W \bigoplus W'$ and if $W$ is T-invariant then $W'$ is not necessarily T-invariant.

Comment: Try a projection map.

Comment: For a second, I thought you had solved the invariant subspace problem...What a disapointment.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A:=\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}$ as a linear map $\in L(V)$ for $V=\Bbb R^2$, and let $W$ be the $x$-axis and $W'$ the $y$-axis.